# Adding multiple fields in join attributes by location in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I want to add multiple fields in "fields to add" using the `join attributes by location` algorithm in the graphical modeler.

It works if I add only one field, like DISTANCE, but when I want to add others it gives me errors. I tried separating with `,`, `;` and `''`, tried with brackets too. Is it possible to add other fields but not all existing fields?

I'm using QGIS 3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should work with `;`, I just tested it successfully (my fields are called **1**, **2**, and **3**):

[image]

Comment: Make sure not to use a space after the semicolon

Answer (score 1):

By using the tool "Join attributes by location" you choose the fields you want to add here:
[image]

Click the botton with the 3 dots and select from the list.

Comment: The tool is different in the graphical modeler. This doesn't apply.